# Mass of iron from the reduction of iron(III) oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry, mole

> Given the equation
>   $$\ce{Fe2O3 + 3H2 -> 2Fe + 3H2O},$$
>   determine how many grams of $\ce{Fe}$ can be produced from $\pu{16.5 g}$ of $\ce{Fe2O3}$.

I've already determined the masses of each component. I believe the next step is convert the masses into moles, but after that, I'm not sure what formula to use.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After finding the moles of $\ce{Fe2O3}$ we see that after balancing the equation, $2$ moles of $\ce{Fe}$ are formed for every mole of $\ce{Fe2O3}$.

But that would be considering that the equation moves completely to the RHS, which is assumed if nothing is explicitly mentioned but not true.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.